# Emacs regexp groups in regex-replace

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I have a bunch of C macros in files, stuff like `NEXT( pL )` which is expanded to `( ( pL ) -> next )`

I want to remove most of them because they're unnecessary.

What I would like to do, is get the text inside the parentheses in the macro, `pL`. I want the replacing regexp to use that text for the rewriting. For example, in Perl I could do something like `/NEXT\(\s*(.+)\s*)` (may be a little incorrect) and then output something like `$1->next`, which should turn a line

```
if ( NEXT( pL ) != NULL ) {
```

into

```
if ( pL->next != NULL ) {
```

In Emacs, I would like to use match groups in an emacs replace-regexp on a file by file basis. I'm not entirely sure how to do this in Emacs.

Comment: `M-x c-macro-expansion` or `M-x c-macro-expand` could be used.  But what you ask for looks like it will need a new function around the `M-x c-macro-expansion` to work on a whole file or buffer.

Comment: c-macro-expand doesn't know the macros though? They are located in a separate file/buffer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
M-x query-replace-regexp NEXT(\([^)]+\)) RET \1->next RET
```

Which can be done inside a function like so (to apply to an entire buffer)

```
(defun expand-next ()
  "interactive"
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "\\<NEXT(\\([^\)]+\\))" nil t)
    (replace-match "\\1->next")))
```

And, to apply this to multiple files, you can mark the files in [Dired and type <kbd>Q</kbd> to do a `query-replace-regexp` on all the marked files](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Operating-on-Files.html#Operating-on-Files) (use the regexp/replacement in the first line of this answer).

Comment: I'm dredging up some old muck here rather than submit a new question since this is the correct topic  ... I'm using Emacs 23.1.  When I use \1 as the replacement, I get "No matches found."  I use the same regexp built from regexp-builder which matches the found text correctly. Any Ideas??